# vim search for exact phrase

Tags: search, vim

After a long day of yak shaving, getting stuck on something super simple and probably being dumb. Vim n00b('ish) to boot. I'm trying to search for an exact phrase, which works for the first result but moving to any different result (n or * - forward, # - back) permutes the result to the first word.

```
/__webpack_require__)
```

matches correctly for the first result, and then proceeds to match only `__webpack_require__` going forward or backward.

I am using yadr, so there are a bunch of vim plugins I don't understand (I know, that's a problem, but one for another day). Any help would be appreciated. Googling is a mess on this topic.

** update **

I did try `\)` but found that actually is not an escape. I also noticed, that searching for `function(modules, export, __webpack_require__)` also permutes after the first result to `function` so something I don't understand is happening here that is probably totally normal and useful, but not when you don't understand it.

Comment: I apologise for a probably dumb comment, but have you tried double quotes `"search string"` or escape sequences for such characters as `)`?

Comment: What do you mean by "permute"?

Comment: @melpomene, permute means search results change: i.e. the first match is precise, but following matches become more permissive. Subsequent matches return __webpack_require__= foo; or __webpack_require__(blah). So the parenthesis is dropped. In the expanded function example, subsequent matches are for anything with the characters function (dropping the rest of the pattern).

It's like the search pattern gets modified after the first result to be just the first 'word'.

Comment: Did you try `/__webpack_require__\)` ?

Comment: @PeterOehlert OK, I get what you're saying now, but that's not what "permute" means.

Comment: This doesn't happen in standard vim. It must be one of your plugins that's doing it.

Comment: As mentioned by @TheSquareCow but I'd like to emphasize: `n` is **not** the same as `*`. If it permutes as you say when using `*`, that's completely normal. If it is when using `n`, that's something to look into *(probably a pluggin)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `n` to move to the next search result  (and `N` for backwards). `*` searches for the current word under the cursor which will cause the change to what you are searching for that you are experiencing.

Comment: I knew I was just being dumb. Back to my cheat sheet.